# Changing a span' location depending on different span

Tags: css, sass

[Inside my Pen](https://codepen.io/tislars/pen/bMMdjE) you can see an image block with a title on the bottom. When the user hovers over the block, a description is shown on the bottom and the title is moved.

However, the title is on the correct location if the description contains 1 line of text. With 2 lines of text, the title is on top the description. How could I have the title always just above the description, without moving it all the way to the top of the block?

```
.trend-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;

  &:hover {
    .transition-title {
      bottom: 35px;
    }

    .trend-text {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 120px;
      color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 15px;
      padding: 0 15px;

    }
  }
}

.trend-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.trend-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.trend-text {
  display: none;
}

.transition-title {
  transition: bottom .1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wrapper class absolute instead of the two spans (`.trend-content`); https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxxbpx. The `.trend-text` does now have a max-height of zero as default. When you hover over it, the max-height will be te same as te container (Can't be a height of `auto` in order to make the transition).